# Angular 10 - Prevent carriage returns from adding spaces at beginning and end of text literal rendered into HTML

Tags: html, angular

I'm writing an application where spacing is critical in the output of some of the text I'm rendering. Users are allowed to highlight text with their mouse, then click a button to "mark" the text. I then later re-render the output with text highlighted that has been marked. I recently noticed an off-by-one issue when doing this though and, when looking at the rendered HTML I could see the problem.

This code

```
<mat-card (mouseup)="mouseUp()" #card>{{article.text}}</mat-card>
```

Produces this result in the HTML

[image: Without Carriage Return]

Whereas this code

```
<mat-card (mouseup)="mouseUp()" #card>
    {{article.text}}
</mat-card>
```

Produces this result in the HTML

[image]

There's a space at the beginning and the end of the text literal in the version with the carriage return in it but I have a couple of issues when trying to remove the carriage return. Firstly, the part of the code where I display the text again with the highlighting shown is much more complex, making it so I can't simply change the carriage returns around. It looks like this.

```
<mat-card class="te-card">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let textGroup of article.textSets; index as i; first as isFirst; last as isLast" >
        <ng-container *ngIf="isFirst || article.textSets[i].rangeStart > article.textSets[i - 1].rangeEnd">
            {{article.text.substring(i === 0 ? 0 : article.textSets[i - 1].rangeEnd, article.textSets[i].rangeStart)}}
            <div class="grouped-text-tab">
                <span [ngClass]="{ 'contributed': markExistsForUserAndType(article.textSets[i].textSetId, 'one')}">1 ({{(article.textSets[i].markMetrics || {"oneCount": 0}).oneCount}})</span> | 
                <span [ngClass]="{ 'contributed': markExistsForUserAndType(article.textSets[i].textSetId, 'two')}">2 ({{(article.textSets[i].markMetrics || {"twoCount": 0}).twoCount}})</span> | 
                <span [ngClass]="{ 'contributed': markExistsForUserAndType(article.textSets[i].textSetId, 'three')}">3 ({{(article.textSets[i].markMetrics || {"threeCount": 0}).threeCount}})</span>
            </div>
            <span class="claim grouped-text" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contribute" [matMenuTriggerData]="{textSetId: article.textSets[i].textSetId}" (click)="setActiveGroupIndex(i)">
                {{article.text.substring(article.textSets[i].rangeStart, article.textSets[i].rangeEnd)}}
            </span>
            <ng-container *ngIf="isLast">
                {{article.text.substring(article.textSets[i].rangeEnd, article.text.length)}}
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</mat-card>
```

In order to format my code to remove carriage returns I would have to add unwanted spacing at the beginning or end, I'd have to turn this well-structured code into something less readable like what you see below. Note that the grouped-text-tab div has been moved up to be at the end of the previous line. (FYI: everything in grouped-text-tab doesn't contain content sensitive to this issue because I won't be highlighting any of that text and have thus left the carriage returns inside that div intact):

```
<mat-card class="te-card">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let textGroup of article.textSets; index as i; first as isFirst; last as isLast" >
        <ng-container *ngIf="isFirst || article.textSets[i].rangeStart > article.textSets[i - 1].rangeEnd">{{article.text.substring(i === 0 ? 0 : article.textSets[i - 1].rangeEnd, article.textSets[i].rangeStart)}}<div class="grouped-text-tab">
                <span [ngClass]="{ 'contributed': markExistsForUserAndType(article.textSets[i].textSetId, 'one')}">1 ({{(article.textSets[i].markMetrics || {"oneCount": 0}).oneCount}})</span> | 
                <span [ngClass]="{ 'contributed': markExistsForUserAndType(article.textSets[i].textSetId, 'two')}">2 ({{(article.textSets[i].markMetrics || {"twoCount": 0}).twoCount}})</span> | 
                <span [ngClass]="{ 'contributed': markExistsForUserAndType(article.textSets[i].textSetId, 'three')}">3 ({{(article.textSets[i].markMetrics || {"threeCount": 0}).threeCount}})</span>
            </div>
            <span class="claim grouped-text" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contribute" [matMenuTriggerData]="{textSetId: article.textSets[i].textSetId}" (click)="setActiveGroupIndex(i)">{{article.text.substring(article.textSets[i].rangeStart, article.textSets[i].rangeEnd)}}</span>
            <ng-container *ngIf="isLast">{{article.text.substring(article.textSets[i].rangeEnd, article.text.length)}}</ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</mat-card>
```

But that's not even the biggest problem I see because if someone just tells their code editor to auto format the code, the functionality will actually break. I see this as the biggest issue really. Functionality *actually* dependent on code layout.

So, I'd like to find a cleaner way to do this. The reason I'm tagging Angular in the title and keywords is because, although this is an HTML issue, if I didn't have Angular involved in the mix `<pre></pre>` would *possibly* be an OK solution. However, with the complexity of my second example and with Angular in the mix, I can't really use that as an option.

I've also tried using the following CSS directives on the mat-card element to no avail.

```
whitespace: pre;
whitespace: pre-wrap;
whitespace: pre-line;
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem on Angular 9. As a result, I was able to decide as follows:

```html
<mat-card (mouseup)="mouseUp()" #card [innerHTML]="article.text">
</mat-card>
```